# How can I get BuildContext in GetX Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```
class UpdateCheckerService extends GetxService{

  final newVersion = NewVersion(
    androidId: 'net.uniqueapps.beautyone',
  );

  UpdateCheckerService() {
    checkUpdate(newVersion);
  }

  void checkUpdate(NewVersion newVersion) {
    newVersion.showAlertIfNecessary(context: Get.context!); //how can I get context here
  }

}
```

I am trying to make a update checker in Flutter with GetX but the newversion plugin asking for context I given the Get.context but It is throwing null.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get.context // this is BuildContext?
Get.context! // this is BuildContext
```

Or you can use this way

```
 Get.context as BuildContext // this is BuildContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Get.context! **or** Get.context as BuildContext